# Google Analytics advanced segments - excluding by user interest

Tags: google-analytics, segment

initialization: company website with product pages and separate ‘careers’ section.

I’m trying to create advanced segment with Google Analytics that would exclude visits that were more focused on careers section.

career URLs are simply:

- /careers
- /careers/job1
- /careers/job2

I tried to use (two statements with AND operator):

```
‘Exclude’ ‘Page’ ‘Begins with’ ‘/careers’ 
AND
‘Exclude’ ‘Pageviews’ ‘Greater than’ ‘1’
```

Is this approach correct? 
Or do I get more reliable results if I use TimeOnPage instead of Pageviews? 
Example TimeOneSite greater than 15 sec.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this: `'Exclude' 'Page' 'Matching RegExp' '/careers.+$'`

It should exclude any visits within the careers section beyond the main careers page.